# Inner loop conditions shall depend on outer loop run

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I build an inner loop such that the loop condition depends on the outer loop run?

My very situation does probably not matter for the code I am looking for, but here it is: I have a crawler that I want to run on changing URLs, where the URL depends on two parameters. The first one is the year and the second one are pages, while the range of pages vary from year to year.

Here is what I tried so far

```
#!/bin/bash

numbers2004={625..721}
numbers2005={723..823}

for year in 2004 2005
do
  for number in numbers$year
  do
    echo "$year $number"
  done
done
```

It should give me

```
2004 625
2004 626
...
2004 720
2004 721
2005 723
2005 724
...
2005 822
2005 823
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With current bash version:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A numbers    # declare associative array
printf -v numbers[2004] "%s " {625..721}
printf -v numbers[2005] "%s " {723..823}

for year in 2004 2005
do
  for number in ${numbers[$year]}
  do
    echo "$year $number"
  done
done
```

Comment: People must not execute the script with `sh` (at least not on Ubuntu), as I did in the beginning. The reason is explained in http://askubuntu.com/a/28325/334172.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant on Cyrus's answer that uses [parameter indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Think_before_using_indirection). However, as the link says, array-based approaches are to be preferred over the use of indirection, as such indirection is a close cousin of [eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), which should be avoided whenever possible.

(I've reduced the ranges of the numbers from those given in the OP just to make the output a bit smaller).

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf -v numbers2004 "%d " {625..635}
printf -v numbers2005 "%d " {723..733}

for year in 2004 2005
do
    numbers="numbers$year"
    for number in ${!numbers}
    do
        printf "%s %s\n" "$year" "$number"
    done
done
```

**output**

```
2004 625
2004 626
2004 627
2004 628
2004 629
2004 630
2004 631
2004 632
2004 633
2004 634
2004 635
2005 723
2005 724
2005 725
2005 726
2005 727
2005 728
2005 729
2005 730
2005 731
2005 732
2005 733
```

Comment: `eval` shouldn't be avoided if the alternative is a degradation of portability and/or performance. Moreover, learning to use `eval` - and the order in which portions of an `eval`'d statement applied and why they apply that way - is a sure-fire path toward better understanding of the shell itself.

Comment: Sure. And the use of `eval` in your & Joseph R.'s answers is perfectly safe, since there's no danger of malicious data getting `eval`ed. Still, `eval` is a tool that needs to be used with caution, and even people who ought to know better have written scripts that `eval` unsafe data. So I prefer to encourage people to look for solutions that don't require `eval`, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I don't like the use of `eval` in my answer - it was used mainly to show how silly relying on brace expansions as iterables can be - it only really comes clear when you consider that the shell has to generate every iterable *then* iterate over each *(same goes for `printf -v {expand}`)*. And so `eval` is not helpful from either a performance standpoint, or - because POSIX requires a certain subset of C mathematics operators and function for shell arithmetic - a portability standpoint. In any case, `eval` is dangerous when *unknown* values are `eval`'d, not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with variable indirection:

```
#!/bin/bash

numbers2004="$(printf "%s " {625..721})"
numbers2005="$(printf "%s " {723..823})"

for year in 2004 2005
do
  for number in $(eval echo \$numbers$year)
  do
    echo "$year $number"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `eval` to do it the way you're trying to do...

```
numbers2004={625..721}
numbers2005={723..823}

for year in 2004 2005
do
  eval 'eval "for number in '"\$numbers$year"'
  do
    echo \"\$year \$number\"
  done"'
done
```

...which prints...

```
2004 625
...
2004 721
2005 723
...
2005 823
```

But that is kind of a horrible way to do it - and not only because the quoting is a nightmare - but probably most of all because your shell does all of the work *twice*. It must first generate all of the `{brace..expanded}` iterables *before* then iterating over each.

Instead maybe:

```
y=4 n=623 c=721
while  [ "$((y+=$c<(c+=102*(c<(n+=1<<(c==n))))))" -lt 6  ] 
do    echo "200$y $n"
done
```

...which prints the same in recent versions of `busybox ash`, `ksh93`, `dash`, `yash`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, and `posh`.

The arithmetic expression can be made slightly more performant for most of those by evaluating parts of it only when necessary like...

```
y=4 n=623 c=721
while [ "$((c<(n+=1)?(y+=(n+=1)<(c+=102)):y))" -lt 6 ] 
do echo "200$y $n"
done
```

...which works identically in all of the aforementioned shells excepting `busybox`. It seems `busybox` always evaluates all sides of the `if expr ? true : false` ternary statement and so fails to iterate as expected.